# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred / Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, swift2

I have a function with this signature written in a Swift project in Xcode 7.3.1:

```
func DLog<T>(@autoclosure object: () -> T, _ file: String = #file, _ function: String = #function, _ line: Int = #line) {
}
```

The compiler complains about `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` for this call:

```
DLog({ var text = "Returning output list\n"; for outline in outlines { text = text + outline.debugDescription + "\n"; }; return text; })
```

When I try to provide the type it complains `Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function`:

```
DLog<String>({ var text = "Returning output list\n"; for outline in outlines { text = text + outline.debugDescription + "\n"; }; return text; })
```

I have tried few more approaches but nothing satisfied the compiler. I have also failed to find a hint how to solve this case.

How to build the text inside the `() => T` argument and pass it to the function properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation fails because of `@autoclosure` attribute. When you pass some expression to function that takes `@autoclosure` the compiler creates a closure with no parameters that returns result of that expression. So, when you pass `{ var text = "Returning output list\n"; for outline in outlines { text = text + outline.debugDescription + "\n"; }; return text; }` then compiler creates a closure returning a closure returning string.

To fix this, you can either add `()` to the end of expression:

```
DLog({ () -> String in var text = "Returning output list\n"; for outline in outlines { text = text + outline.debugDescription + "\n"; }; return text; }())
```

or simplify expression to simple method call, e.g.

```
DLog(outlines.reduce("Returning output list\n") { $0 + $1.debugDescription + "\n"; })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is causing it, but compiling it in swift 3 make this error message appear:

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

So I tried to explicitly add the return type for the closure:

```
DLog(
    { () -> String in 
        var text = "Returning output list\n" 
        for outline in outlines { 
            text = text + outline.debugDescription + "\n"; 
        } 
        return text 
    }
)
```

and it worked.

Comment: I am getting `Cannot invoke 'DLog' with an argument list of type '(() -> String)'` in Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: Could this be because you're specifying a closure when the parameter's type has `@autoclosure`? You can't `@autoclosure` a closure.

Comment: @alik try removing the auto closure attribute

Comment: I have got `Closure parameter prior to parameters with default arguments will not be treated as a trailing closure` so I put the closure to the end of the parameter list. However, calling `var value = object(); print("\(fileURL) \(function)[\(line)]: " + String(reflecting: value));` results in printing `(Function)` instead of the contents of `text`.